# How come people are confused I asked user is the day 05/05/05 or 05/05/05 or 05/05/05?

Tags: dates

I just don't know why can't they answer a simple question, which date format are they using: 05/05/05 or 05/05/05 or 05/05/05, why can't they answer it?
Here's what I mean, why can't they answer this, and how would I improve this, what I even do that confuses the user when I create a UI about date format they're using:
[image]

Comment: Hello Jesse, this is very confusing, please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Aline I mean dates are written differently across the world so why does 05/05/05 and 05/05/05 confuse people when  picking a date format?

Comment: why do you have 05/05/05 repeated multiple times? how is a user supposed to know which one means what?

Answer (score 4):

Users are **confused** because you have multiple rows that are *the exact same option*.
They are **scared** because it's accompanied with a severe warning that "*Once selected, it cannot be changed!*".

As presented, it is impossible for the user to ensure that they are selecting the correct format, and impossible to fix it later.

Try **pairing a more familiar example date with annotations of the format** each date is using. *Do not use the incredibly ambiguous March 5, 0005 as your example date.*

```
Select your preferred short date format:

(o)  M/D/YYYY    →  4/5/2017
( )  M/D/YY      →  4/5/17
( )  MM/DD/YY    →  04/05/17
( )  MM/DD/YYYY  →  04/05/2017
( )  YY/MM/DD    →  17/04/05
( )  YYYY-MM-DD  →  2017-04-05
( )  DD-MMM-YY   →  04-Apr-17
```

Lastly, I'd recommend doing whatever you can to **allow the user to change this later**.

For a real world example, here is the date format selector in Windows 10:

[image: Windows short date format selection]